# Update Calculated date if not already entered

Tags: calculated-column

I have a field Closed_Date which is automatically calculated as 
=IF([Issue Status]="Closed",Modified, "")

But this gets updated everytime I edit the entry and save.

How do I update the field only if Closed_Date is blank without creating circular reference?

Answer (score 0):

Your formula updated the Closed_Date every time you re-save an item already closed. And you probably have found out that you cannot reference your calculated field within its formula.

Unless you have another field that can indicate if the previous change is to close the item in your list (e.g. previous status), you can't.

An alternative to your calculated field is a normal date field that gets updated through workflow.